# Not every over-under-category is cocomplete

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Something is wrong between me and Hirschhorn: point 3 of this result (in the book *Model categories and their localizations*):

> #### 7.6.4. Homotopy in undercategories and overcategories.
>
> **Theorem 7.6.5.** Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model category.
>
> 1. If $A$ is an object of $\mathcal M$, then the category $(A \downarrow \mathcal M)$ of objects of $\mathcal M$ under A (see Definition 7.6.1) is a model category in which a map is a weak equivalence, fibration, or cofibration if it is one in $\mathcal M$.
> 2. If $X$ is an object of $\mathcal M$, then the category $(\mathcal M \downarrow X)$ of objects of $\mathcal M$ over $X$ ( Definition 7.6.2) is a model category in which a map is a weak equivalence, fibration, or cofibration if it is one in $\mathcal M$.
> 3. If $A$ and $B$ are objects in $\mathcal M$, then the category $(A \downarrow \mathcal M \downarrow B)$ of objects of $\mathcal M$ under $A$ and over $B$ (see Definition 7.6.3) is a model category in which a map is a weak equivalence, fibration, or cofibration if it is one in $\mathcal M$.
>
> Pʀᴏᴏғ. This follows directly from the definitions. ❑

seems to be false taken as it is: either I misunderstood something, or $(A\downarrow \mathcal{M}\downarrow B)$ is seldom cocomplete (what should an initial object be?).

Is Hirschhorn wrong? Does he mean something different from the result he states?

Comment: Does Hirschorn require his model categories to be (co)complete? Or does he call these closed model categories?

Comment: He explicitly requires _every_ limit and colimit to exist. But this is not a point, since even in the weakest possible definition you need at least finite limits to speak about cofibrant/fibrant objects...

Comment: And my problem is precisely that $(A\downarrow{\bf Set}\downarrow B)$ (or $(A\downarrow{\bf Top}\downarrow B)$) has no initial object

Comment: It seems to me that it's an oversight then. For example if $C$ has is the discrete category on two objects $X$ and $Y$ (ie. there are no morphisms besides the identities) then $(X \downarrow C \downarrow Y)$ is empty, so it can't possibly be complete or cocomplete. Edit: But then neither is $C$...

Comment: What frightens me is that the result right after that (solutions to lifting problems are uniue up to homotopy) sensibly relies on this. Obviously, one can prove the same result in a different way. Maybe. But Hirschhorn explicitly says "blah is cofibrant in $(A\downarrow \mathcal{C}\downarrow B)$, hence ..."; didn't he check that?

Comment: I really don't know then. Because eg $(\{0\} \downarrow \mathtt{Set} \downarrow \emptyset)$ *is* empty and this time $\mathtt{Set}$ is a model category with all the structure we could want...

Comment: I mailed Hirschhorn. Thanks to anybody else who will answer!

Comment: The category in question is a disjoint union of model categories. Perhaps that suffices for whatever purposes intended.

Comment: +1 to Zhen Lin. (For every morphism $f \colon A \to B$, you get a model category whose objects are those $A \to X \to B$ whose composition is equal to $f$.)

Comment: I was aware of that, but I find it unsatsifying, since there are no particular "purposes" in the result as it is stated. Whatever!

Comment: Hirschhorn answered. "I think you're right. I wrote this so long ago that I don't at all recall what I was thinking; I need to think this through and see how to repair the damage." Let's see :) (I felt like Russell today)

Answer (score 2):

The category $(A\downarrow \mathcal{M}\downarrow B)$ is not necessarily a model category, as it can fail to be complete or cocomplete (or both). For example, $(\{*\} \downarrow \mathsf{Set} \downarrow \varnothing)$ is not a model category: it is empty! There is no map from a singleton to the empty set.

However one can define, for every $f : A \to B$, the category:
$$(A\downarrow \mathcal{M}\downarrow B)_f = \{ A \xrightarrow{g} X \xrightarrow{h} B \mid h \circ g = f \}$$
over objects over $B$ and under $A$ such that the morphisms compose to $f$. Then it's clear that
$$(A\downarrow \mathcal{M}\downarrow B) = \bigsqcup_{f \in \hom_\mathcal{M}(A,B)} (A\downarrow \mathcal{M}\downarrow B)_f$$
is a disjoint union of categories (the different components don't interact at all), and each $(A\downarrow \mathcal{M}\downarrow B)_f$ is a model category with weak equivalences, fibrations and cofibrations as in Hirschhorn's definition (for example the initial object is $A \to A \xrightarrow{f} B$, the terminal object is $A \xrightarrow{f} B \to B$).